# How to be safe against CVE-2019-8912?

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, security

I've read in news that there is a new Kernel bug
https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2019-8912
Is it safe to use my PC until it gets fixed ? Can someone use this exploit to steal my paypal account, my money and other accounts ?
Is there a way to be safe against this type of exploit ?

Comment: You'll have to wait until patch is released and apply the patch,  or wait till newer kernel is released with the fix and upgrade.

Comment: before loading latest kernel, some way to protect youself while browsing: use a strong unique kernel for sensitive (money related) site, do not browse as root, use official repository, etc ...

Answer (score 0):

Kernels 4.20.12, 4.19.25 and 4.14.103 released today (2019-02-23) all contain the fix for CVE-2019-8912. (commit eb5e6869125f69dd28513f92992d97ec62bb9773 net: crypto set sk to NULL when af_alg_release.) Wait until there are updated kernel packages available for Debian or compile your own kernel.
Source:
https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/ChangeLog-4.19.25

If you don't use the crypto API you can of course blacklist the relevant kernel module as a workaround in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf:
blacklist af_alg